# Image tabs with OpenCV or Matplotlib

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

Is there a simple way to display multiple images in same window, so I can switch between them using tabs or drop-down list with OpenCV or matplotlib. I frequently need to display a lot of images for debugging purposes, so I run out of space on the screen. Or should I go with some UI library for that?

Comment: Not with OpenCV, for sure

Comment: OpenGL can do it, or SDL. If you use SDL, youll need to convert the Mat object to a stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use matplotlib and widgets such as shown below.
The same way this example switches between different parameters of a function, you could e.g load different images from file. Some code example from your side would be helpful to elaborate further.

Code from http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/buttons.html :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

freqs = np.arange(2, 20, 3)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*freqs[0]*t)
l, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2)


class Index(object):
    ind = 0

    def next(self, event):
        self.ind += 1
        i = self.ind % len(freqs)
        ydata = np.sin(2*np.pi*freqs[i]*t)
        l.set_ydata(ydata)
        plt.draw()

    def prev(self, event):
        self.ind -= 1
        i = self.ind % len(freqs)
        ydata = np.sin(2*np.pi*freqs[i]*t)
        l.set_ydata(ydata)
        plt.draw()

callback = Index()
axprev = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
axnext = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
bnext = Button(axnext, 'Next')
bnext.on_clicked(callback.next)
bprev = Button(axprev, 'Previous')
bprev.on_clicked(callback.prev)

plt.show()
```